# Azure sentinal alert vs monitor alert

Tags: azure-monitoring, azure-sentinel

In Azure kusto query window We can create two alerts

1. Azure Monitor Alert
2. Azure Sentinel Alert

What are the difference between these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are two different things. In general Azure Monitor alert will be related to a performance metric type of alert maybe when your `CPU on VM is at 75%` and you want to be notified about it via e-mail/SMS/webhook etc. and Sentinel alert is being triggered when there has been some security alert in your environment for example  `Failed SSH brute force attack`, the Sentinel alerts are being correlated into actionable security incidents to reduce noise.

Hope it helps :)